# 1 controller for multiple NSWindows

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have an applicationion that has multiple `NSWindow`s. I'd like to control them all with a single `NSWindowController`. Is this possible? If so, how do I initialize the controllers with multiple NSWindow nibs?

Answer (score 0):

NSWindowController was designed to own a single NSWindow (in the _window property), so your design goal is fighting the framework.  A better idea is to have a separate NSWindowController for each window, then write a master controller class that owns and manages the cluster of window controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Although architecturally speaking this is not a good idea, it can be achieved. For this, you will need to use separate outlets for the windows you need to manage, and you can use [+[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSBundle_UIKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/loadNibNamed:owner:options:) to load multiple nibs into the same NSWindowController (just make sure you don't have conflicting outlets).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single NSWindowController ***subclass*** that incorporates the functionality needed by multiple windows, but you'll need a separate ***instance*** of that controller for each window.

You typically would use an Application Delegate or some other general controller class to open the multiple windows, instantiating the window controllers as needed. For example:

```
- (IBAction)showFirstWindow:(id)sender {

   if (!self.firstWindowController) {
       NSStoryboard *storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
       self.firstWindowController = [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"OneWindow"];

       // initialize any variables for the window controller 
   }

   [self.firstWindowController showWindow:self];
}

- (IBAction)showSecondWindow:(id)sender {

   if (!self.secondWindowController) {
       NSStoryboard *storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
       self.secondWindowController = [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"OneOrAnotherWindow"];

       // initialize any variables for the window controller 
   }

   [self.secondWindowController showWindow:self];
}
```

Note that you can reuse the same window controller from the storyboard for the second window, or you can use a different window controller from the storyboard with another identifier, with **both** of them sharing your single custom subclass; just specify your class instead of NSWindowController in the Custom Class panel of the storyboard inspector.